# How to build a gcc multilib tool chain?

Tags: gcc, x86-64

I'm trying to build a gcc multilib tool chain on AMD64 version of fresh ubuntu 14.04 installation. It only has a x86_64 gcc and g++ installation without multilib support. My configuration line is 
`../configure --disable-checking --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib` 
When I make it fails somewhere around building 32bit libgcc complaining about a missing sys/cdefs.h
I can't post a build log right now but the error occurs in the folder `objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgcc/`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need `libc6-dev-i386` and Trusty does indeed have a multilib gcc: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/gcc-multilib

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted to build a multilib toolchain myself. I'll try installing that package.

Comment: Sorry, but "It only has a x86_64 gcc and g++ installation without multilib support." does not sound like "Yeah I know".

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't much clear, I meant that I know trusty has multilib support. Why can't we build multilib packages just with 64bit compiler? If we should have dual arch tool chain to do that, how did they build the first multilib tool chain?

Comment: You need to install `libc6-dev-i386` then it should work.

Comment: That package is a part of multilib tool chain right?

Comment: You should get known to the Ubuntu package system first before asking such questions. Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386` or `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-multilib g++-4.8-multilib`.

Comment: @Thomas: the OP wants to **build** a multilib toolchain and merely gave information about the host toolchain he intends to use for the build process. Why do you keep recommending installing a prebuilt toolchain when the OP clearly asks how to *build* his own?

Comment: @Madushan: you need to give (at least!) the exact error you experience, the versions of the tarballs you are using, the commands you are trying to run etc. The question the way it stands is pretty much unclear.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: 1. This question is more than a year old. Don't push old questions for no reason. 2. `libc6-dev-i386` is required to build a multilib gcc... 3. The OP just wants to install the toolchain by hand because he doesn't know how to install the same toolchain via `apt-get`.