# Running C++ code in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: c++, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed hadoop 2.5.2 in CentOS VM. I am pretty new to hadoop and am trying to execute c++ code in hadoop 2.x based on [tutorials](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop)

I see that in Hadoop 2.x versions, there is no folder `(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/`. I see there are includes under `$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/include` and library files like `hadoopipes.a` under `$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native/libhadooppipes.a` etc. I tweaked my makefile like this:

```
 CC = g++
    HADOOP_INSTALL = /usr/local/hadoop
    CPPFLAGS = -m32 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/include

    wordcount: WordCount.cpp
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/lib/native -lhadooppipes \
        -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@

and changed in code ( rest of code is same as in the link above )

      #include "Pipes.hh" 
      #include "TemplateFactory.hh" 
      #include "StringUtils.hh"

when I compile I get
    $ make wordcount
    g++ -m32 -I/usr/local/hadoop/include WordCount.cpp -Wall -L/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes \
        -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o wordcount
    /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadooppipes.a when searching for -lhadooppipes
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhadooppipes
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone give pointers as to how to compile c++ on hadoop 2.x.  ( I can execute c++ program in hadoop 1.x though. What I am interested is , how to execute c++ program using hadoop pipes in hadoop 2.x)   Thanks in advance

Comment: "...skipping incompatible" -  mostly printed when you are trying to link 32-bits libraries on 64-bits system. If it is really 64-bit, try "-m64" instead of "-m32". And to build with 32bit binary, you have to - install sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib and  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-dev

Comment: I am using centos 32 bit version( i686 ). g++ version is 32 bit      # file /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++: ELF 32-bit LSB executable.  But the library of hadoop shows                                                              # objdump -f libhadooppipes.a 
In archive libhadooppipes.a:

HadoopPipes.cc.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64,

Comment: But the library of hadoop shows i386:x86-64 ( does this mean it supports both 32/64 bit)? I tried both -m32 and -m64. Both are giving error. Please advice
# g++ -m64 -I/usr/local/hadoop/include WordCount.cpp -Wall -L/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o wordcount
WordCount.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in.

Comment: # g++ -m32 -I/usr/local/hadoop/include WordCount.cpp -Wall -L/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o wordcount
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadooppipes.a when searching for -lhadooppipes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhadooppipes
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: How to compile 32 bit binary by linking it to hadoop archive ( file format elf64-x86-64 architecture: i386:x86-64).Please advice

Answer (score 1):

**Question**:

> How to compile 32 bit binary by linking it to hadoop archive ( file
>   format elf64-x86-64 architecture: i386:x86-64).Please advice

**Answer**: You need *multilib* for that. If it is already installed as on Ubuntu 14.04 or on Arch Linux, you would have to enable 32-bit applications on 64-bit system.

For example, as this [source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multilib) says -

> Enabling the *multilib* repository allows the user to run and build
>   32-bit applications on 64-bit installations of Arch Linux. multilib
>   creates a directory containing 32-bit instruction set libraries inside
>   /usr/lib32/, which 32-bit binary applications may need when executed.

Otherwise, you have to install *multilib* -

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-dev
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042854/how-to-build-a-gcc-multilib-tool-chain) also can help. And Google more about multilib support.